# Google maps api in Google spreadsheets for distance (miles or meters) calculation between addresses/locations

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets, maps, google-sheets-api

First, the context:

I have one spreadsheet with two columns containing hundreds of addresses (e.g. postcodes). I found this short script that allows me to quickly calculate the driving distance between the two postcodes

```
  function dist(pointa,pointb) {
     Utilities.sleep(1000);
     var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
        .setOrigin(pointa)
        .setDestination(pointb)
        .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
        .getDirections();
     var route = directions.routes[0];
     var txtA = route.legs[0].distance.value;
     return txtA;
   }
```

Where pointa is address 1 (origin) in cell A1 and pointb is address 2 (destination) in cell B1. using the script above I can do this in cell C1: `=dist(A1,B1)` and I get the distance in meters. If I do this: `=dist(A1,B1)/1609` I get a fairly accurate distance in miles.

Second, the problem:

1. Because of the continuous information requests, there are quite a few errors coming up which affect the stability of this short code with a great potential. For just a few addresses it is not a problem but it kind of misses the point when working with hundreds of addresses.
2. Error 1: *Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch protected host rateMax. Try `Utilities.sleep(1000)` between calls. (line 3).* As you can see above, I have included the `Utilities.sleep()` but it does not correct this error
3. Error 2: *TypeError: Cannot read property "legs" from undefined. (line 9).* This is extremely frustrating. I can redress it if I add a space in one of the addresses. Then if I close the tab and re-open it the error is back and I can correct it if I remove the space.

All things considered and thinking that something like this would be useful for more people, are there any ideas on how I can make it more stable. It would be even better if there is a way to call the distance between two addresses and then automatically stop the script from looking every time the spreadsheet is accessed or refreshed i.e. if there is a need to refresh, then the function has to be entered again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. In case it is not obvious I have to point that I am on a steep learning curve when it comes to the basics of google script; please excuse any major obvious mistakes, constructive criticism is encouraged.

Many thanks,

Comment: Instead of using a custom function, you could use something link an "On Edit" or "On Change" trigger to update only the current row that was just edited.  If all the data doesn't need to constantly be updated, but just one row, when something changes, the "On Edit" trigger might work.  I would use an "installable" On Edit trigger and not the "Simple" trigger.  An "On Edit" function can check which row was just edited, and update just the calculations in that row.  You'll need to use the event object, get the range, then get the row of the range, or get the active cell.

Comment: Error 1 has been answered in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535722/how-do-i-put-utilities-sleep-between-function-calls).

Comment: Thank you both.  @noogui the second link (Error 2) does not work any chance you can try again? Much appreciated