# How to improve LockService in this context, using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, lock-service

I'm using `LockService` for a script that locates the active row and a couple of criteria and ifthey match, then an email is sent.
However, I'm seeing `Service invoked too many times` more frequently that I thought I'd see, so I'm not sure I'm using it correctly.

Is getting the lock only after the criteria are met better down the road, instead of making it unavailble even when "that run" doesn't meet the criteria?

It's got an installable trigger set on edit basis, so I'm escaping it as soon as possible before getting the lock, but still...

Here's the code:

```
function sendEmail() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Todays Tests V2') {
    return;
  }

  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
    lock.waitLock(3000); // wait 03 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 03 seconds.');
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b> Server Busy. Please try after some time <p>");
  }

  const testSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Todays Tests V2");
  const row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  const col = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const emailSent = testSheet.getRange(row, 14, 1, 1).getValue();
  const sendResults = testSheet.getRange(row, 15, 1, 1).getValue();

  const formRespSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  const formRespRng = formRespSheet.getRange(2, 13, formRespSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2);
  const formRespValues = formRespRng.getValues();

  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == testSheet.getSheetName() 
    && row > 5 
    && col == 15 
    && sendResults == true) {
    const email = testSheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
    const name = testSheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue() + ' ' + testSheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
    const testNo = testSheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Subject", name + " Msg.", { name: 'Custom Senders Name' });

    for (var n = 0; n < formRespValues.length; n++) {
      if (formRespValues[n][1] == testNo) {
        formRespSheet.getRange('M' + (2 + n)).setValue('Yes');
      }
    }
  }
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

I'd love to understand how this can be improved.

Thank you!

Comment: Please specify which specific Google service has caused the `Service invoked too many times` error Or share the complete error. I'm also wondering if you've already checked the official Apps Script's [Quotas for Google Services: Exception messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) as this will explain the error that you're seeing.

Comment: @IrvinJayG., the error comes up when the script is triggered more than once at the same time. It's known that the error fires when they predict it'll hit the limit, given how it's running. I was curious to see what folks suggest in terms of getting the lock prior or after the criteria are met. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Does this sample implementation from [How do I put Utilities.sleep() between function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34539071) with LockService work for you?

Comment: I'll check that one in-depth. Thank you!